# Identify sequence of events based on certain rules

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need help on identifying a sequence of events in SQL Server 2008 R2 rows please:

This is the sample data with [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/141eb3/2):

```
   ID   EventTime       TypeID             EventNr
    1   06:34:51        1
    2   06:35:51        3
    3   06:36:51        40
    4   06:37:51        10
    5   06:48:51        1
    6   06:49:51        2
    7   06:50:51        4
    8   06:51:51        40
    9   06:52:51        5
    10  06:53:51        10
```

I need help on identifying Event Nrs please - 
Rules that I must follow:

- An event starts start with TypeID 1 (`@StartTypeID`).
- An event ends with TypeID 10 (`@EndTypeID`).
- An event has a different TypeID after `@StartTypeID`, and before `@EndTypeID`.
- And there must be more than 5 minutes between EventNrs.

This is the explected result for the above example:

```
 ID EventTime   TypeID  Notes                                               EventNr
1   06:34:51    1       Starts with TypeID @StartID 1     (OK)                     1
2   06:35:51    3       Has different TypeID in sequence before @EndID reached(OK) 1
3   06:36:51    40                                                                 1
4   06:37:51    10      Ends with @EndID 10 + >5min before next Event(OK EventEnd) 1

5   06:48:51    1       Starts with TypeID @StartID 1                              2
6   06:49:51    2       Has different TypeID in sequence before @EndID reached     2
7   06:50:51    4                                                                  2
8   06:51:51    40                                                                 2
9   06:52:51    5       Has different TypeID in sequence before  @EndID reached    2
10  06:53:51    10      Ends with @EndID 10                                        2
```

SQL for creating the data sample:

```
declare @FirstTypeID int = 1

declare @LastTypeID int = 10


create table #T (ID int identity , EventTime datetime, TypeID int)
insert into #T(EventTime,TypeID)
values
 (DATEADD(minute,-30,getdate()),1)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-29,getdate()),3)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-28,getdate()),40)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-27,getdate()),10)  
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-16,getdate()),1)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-15,getdate()),2)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-14,getdate()),4)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-13,getdate()),40)
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-12,getdate()),5) 
 ,(DATEADD(minute,-11,getdate()),10)    


select * from #T

drop table #T
```

Comment: What if TypeID 1 is immediately followed by TypeID 10? What if TypeID 10 is *not* immediately followed by TypeID 1? What if there is more than 5 min between events either of both of which are *not* TypeID 1 or 10? What if there is *not* more than 5 min between TypeID 10 and the following TypeID 1?

Comment: hi, if any of those events occur, then the event nr does not increment please. Type1 immediately Type10 (no event in between -stay on current event nr). Type 10 not immediately followed by Type1 (stay on current event nr) . Not more than 5min between 10 and 1 (stay on current event Nr) If I can get an idea of what you can recommend then I can sort out the dates based on your recommended approach but I have no clue where to start please

Comment: I would start with enumerating the rows. That would allow me to join the dataset to itself matching each row with its neighbours (so it would probably be two self-joins) to look at their properties. In fact, that's what I'm working on at the moment. (But I thought I'd let you know in case you want to try something on your own.)

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I included auto identity for simplicity, but am using row_number for enumeration. are you referring to partitioning, which is effectively what Im attempting - to partition by groups?

Comment: No, I meant global enumeration. At least that's what seemed to me necessary as the first step. Your IDs do indeed look like row numbers, I just wasn't sure I could rely on that and thanks for clarifying that I was right to doubt. :) As for enumeration in partitions, that might be needed as well, I'm not certain. You are perfectly free to explore that direction, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gives the correct output:

```
With ord as (
    Select first, last 
        , EventNr = ROW_NUMBER() Over(order by first) 
    From (
        Select first = t1.EventTime, last = t2.EventTime
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by t1.ID order by t2.eventTime) 
        From #T t1
        Inner Join #T t2 On t2.EventTime > t1.EventTime  and t2.TypeID = @LastTypeID
        Where t1.TypeID = @FirstTypeID
    ) ids
    Where rn = 1
)
Select t.ID, t.EventTime, t.TypeID, o.EventNr From #T t
Inner Join ord o On t.EventTime >= o.first and t.EventTime <= o.last
Order By o.EventNr, t.EventTime
```

I didn't use Column ID for ordering because it seems to be specific to your samplte.

Comment: I know this is an old answer and would like to know if it could be improved by using windowing functions FIRST_VALUE / LAST_VALUE? Better yet read firstTypeID and lastTypeID pairs from a table. Thanks in advance.